# Generate tests from file in Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a JSON file in roughly the following format:

```py
{
  "frontend_tests": [
       { name: "button_test", data: [ ... ] },
       { name: "button_test_2", data: [ ... ] }
   ],
   "backend_tests": [ 
       { name: "api_test", data: [...] }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to generate tests from this file dynamically. Here's my current approach:

```py
def run_test(test_ctx, data):
    print(data)

with open("frontend_tests.json", "r") as f:
    tests = json.loads(f.read())
    for (section_name, section_tests) in tests.items():
        test_methods = {}
        for test in section_tests:
            def test_wrapper(self):
                data = test["steps"]
                run_test(self, data)
            name = test["name"].replace(" ", "_")
            name = f"test_{name}"
            test_methods[name] = test_wrapper
        section_name = section_name.replace(" ", "_")
        section_name = section_name.upper()
        test_klass = type(section_name, (unittest.TestCase,), test_methods)
```

I can see that the test classes & methods are being properly generated, yet no tests are run. What's going on? Do I need to assign the `test_klass` variable to something in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to assign the test_klass variable to something in the global scope?

Yes, that'd be it.

Try e.g.

```
globals()[section_name] = test_klass
```

and maybe in the longer run consider a more elegant testing framework such as [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) where that sort of dynamism is easy to implement with `pytest.mark.parametrize` :)